# Disable and enable an anchor tag based

Tags: php, jquery, anchor

How do i disable and enable an anchor tag based on `order_status` condition? I want to make my `receipt` button only be able to click when the order_status been updated to `($irow['order_status'] == 5`. It would be much appreciated if you all can provide me a code demo to show me how should I implement this using jquery. Thanks!

```
    <div class="container mt-3 mb-5">

  <div class="row form-group">
    <?php
  $total_price = 0.00;
  $total_quantity = 0;

  $sql = "SELECT *, sum(purchase_price) purchase_price, sum(quantity) quantity FROM ordered_items WHERE user_id = '$user_id' GROUP BY order_id ORDER BY order_datetime DESC";
  $query = $conn->query($sql);

  if (!mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    echo '
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <strong><span class="iconify" data-icon="ic:round-remove-shopping-cart" data-width="30px" data-height="30px" data-inline="false"></span> You have no order</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    ';
  } else {

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      $total_price = $row['purchase_price'];
      if($total_price < 500.00 && $row['item_deliver_method'] == 'Delivery'){
        $grand_total = $total_price + 10.00;
      }else{
        $grand_total = $total_price;
      }
        
      $total_quantity = $row['quantity'];
      //$grand_total = $row['grand_total'];

  ?>
  
    <div class="col-12 form-group orderidfocus">
      <div class="product-wrapper" id="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>">
        <p class="pl-2 pt-2 pr-2">OrderID: <?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>
        </br><?php echo $row['item_deliver_method']; ?> Date: <?php echo $row['delivery_date']; ?></p> 
        <hr style="border: 0.5px dashed #DBDBDB;">
        <?php 
        $isql = "SELECT * FROM ordered_items LEFT JOIN products ON ordered_items.product_id = products.id WHERE ordered_items.order_id = '".$row['order_id']."' ";
        $iquery = $conn->query($isql);
        while ($irow = $iquery->fetch_assoc()) {
          if($irow['order_status'] == 1) {
            $order_status = '<div class="badge-secondary font-italic p-1">Waiting for Response </div>';
          }
          if($irow['order_status'] == 2) {
            $order_status = '<div class="badge-warning font-italic p-1">Preparing</div>';
          }
          if($irow['order_status'] == 3) {
            $order_status = '<div class="badge-info font-italic p-1">In Delivery</div>';
          }
          if($irow['order_status'] == 4) {
            $order_status = '<div class="badge-danger font-italic p-1">Ready to Pick up</div>';
          }
          if($irow['order_status'] == 5) {
            $order_status = '<div class="badge-success font-italic p-1">Completed</div>';
          }
        ?>
        
        <div class="row h-100 pl-2 pr-2 form-group">
          <div class="col-12">
             <small class="float-right"><?php echo $order_status; ?></small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 my-auto form-group">
            <img class="order-page-img-thumbnail" src="images/product-main/<?php echo $irow['product_photo']; ?>" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 pl-0 pr-0 my-auto form-group">
            <div class="product-title"><?php echo $irow['product_title']; ?></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 pl-0 my-auto form-group">
            <div class="product-price" style="text-align: right;">
              RM<?php echo $irow['product_price']; ?>/<?php echo $irow['product_quantity']; ?><br>
              <span style="color: #00644C;">X<?php echo $irow['quantity']; ?></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      <?php } ?>
        
        <hr style="border: 0.5px dashed #DBDBDB;">
        <div class="row justify-content-end pl-2 pr-1">
          <div class="col-3 my-auto form-group pr-0">
            <p class="cat-title" style="text-align: left;font-size: 13px;">Qty: <?php echo $total_quantity; ?>KG</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5 my-auto form-group pl-0">
            <p class="cat-title" style="text-align: right;font-size: 13px;">Amount: RM<?php echo number_format($grand_total,2); ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 form-group pull-right text-center pl-0">
            <a id="receiptbtn" target="_blank" href="receipt.php?order_id=<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" class="btn addtocart" style="font-size: 12px;"><span class="iconify" data-icon="bx:bx-download" data-inline="false"></span> Receipt</a>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this using jQuery? Use PHP to either output the link, or not. (Or to not give it a `href` attribute, or to output only the span without the `a` around it, depending on how exactly you want it to behave.)

Comment: @CBroe can you show me the demo codes on how should I implement the explanation you did?

Comment: How much “demo” does wrapping something into an `if` need? Please _try_ something, instead of asking for “demo code” right away. If you are having problems with this, then show what you tried, and explain what exactly the problem with it was.